# Create iPad layout like Word,excel or Twitter app

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I need some tips to create a layout like this on iPad app.

[image]

I know the `UISplitViewController` but is not possible adjust the left pane (Master Controller).

How can I get this kind of layout? What kinds of components I need to use?

Thanks!!

Comment: simply solution would be two view controllers, one for the side panel one for the content. Mimicing a spit view controller logic for updating content.

Comment: Can you explain with more detail the idea? I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you mean. One ViewController for the blue area, another ViewController for the Content area, and both inside in another ViewController?

Comment: Pretty much yep. One view controller with two child view controllers.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep looking for information about